# Trying to use modulus or fmod, but both are giving my program problems?

Tags: c++, if-statement, modulus

I had problems using modulus trying to divide by decimals. I switched to fmod for choices 3 and 4, but then the program would stop working after choosing the inches when you selected choices 3 and 4. I would like to stay with modulus as that is as far as we have gotten in class, but I am open to other ways as well.

```
int inches, choice, feet, yards;
float centimeters, meters;
float locentimeters, lometers;
int meternum, centnum;
meternum = 39.370;
centnum = .39370;



cout << "Display the entered length in:\n"
    << "1.\tfeet\n"
    << "2.\tyards\n"
    << "3.\tcentimeters\n"
    << "4.\tmeters\n\n"
    << "Enter your choice:\n";
cin >> choice;
cout << "Please enter the length in inches:\n";
cin >> inches;


if (choice == 1)
{
    feet = (inches / 12);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    cout << feet << " feet" << inches % 12 << " inches\n";
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    yards = (inches / 36);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    cout << yards << " yards" << inches % 36 << " inches\n";
}
else if (choice == 3)
{
    centimeters = (inches / .39370);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    locentimeters = (inches % centnum);
    cout << centimeters << locentimeters << " centimeters\n";
}
else if (choice == 4)
{
    meters = (inches / 39.370);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    lometers = (inches % meternum);
    cout << meters << lometers << " meters\n";
}
else
    cout << "That is an invalid entry.\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

The operator `%`  shall have integral type.  And `centnum` is an itself an `int`.  You initialize it with `.39370` which converted to `int` is 0.  This is why in menu 3 you get a divide by zero:

```
locentimeters = (inches % centnum);  // diveide by 0
```

And `meternum` is also an `int`.  You initialize it to `39.370`, which converted to int will be `39`.  This is why in menu 4 you get inacurate resuts:

```
lometers = (inches % meternum);  // meternum is 39 and not 39.370
```

If you define the constants as being double instead of int would not be sufficient:

- `%` requires and integral type diviser. So with a `double` you won't be able to compile.
- [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) is defined to be remainders from an integral quotient.

**The Solution:**

First step is to define your constants with the right type:

```
const double meternum = 39.370; 
const double centnum = .39370;
```

Then you replace `%` by `fmod()`.  On the same time the result of `fmod` makes only sence if you take the integral part of the division using `floor()`. Like this:

```
...
else if (choice == 3)
{
    centimeters = floor(inches / centnum);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    locentimeters = fmod(inches,centnum);
    cout << centimeters << locentimeters << " centimeters\n";
}
else if (choice == 4)
{
    meters = floor(inches/ meternum);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);
    lometers = fmod(inches,meternum);
    cout << meters << lometers << " meters\n";
}
...
```

***Small remark:*** A good habit is to either use doubles with double literals like 3.370 or to use floats with floating literals like 3.370**f**.  If you mix floats with double litterals you risk to have subtle rounding issues.